# A new way to see numbers

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic

I recently watched a talk by Jacob Barnett in which he showed a way that he could see numbers which is as follows:
[image]
He also said that the rotation of lines would represent arithmetic operations. Any ideas on how this works? The subject in question is here:
https://youtu.be/Uq-FOOQ1TpE?t=79

Comment: multiplication by the imaginary number $i$ can be thought of as rotation in the complex plane

Comment: "Stop learning" is beyond silly. One should both have an understanding of what others have developed and think for oneself.

Comment: How can this get $3$ upvotes although the message is to stop learning ?

Comment: There are $31$ lines here, unless I am miscounting.  So I guess you are to imagine that one of these lines counts for $2$ or something.  Why not?

Answer (score 3):

This is some funny way of telling the story...

Well... you have 5 different colors so it's $2^5 = 32$.

Seriously... this is just some fractal-like structure where each color represents a new step done. At each step you double the number of lines by drawing 2 new cross lines in a new color. The two new lines cross a line from the previous last "generation of lines".

The only "problem" is that the red line represents the number $2$ but that's OK, I guess.

So the red line is generation 1.
The two green lines are generation 2.
The blue ones are generation 3 and so on.

In computer science this is a called a perfect binary tree.